# Signature validation failed. Token does not have a kid. // .Net core 6 Jwt token

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, jwt

```
public class JwtService
{
    private string secureKey = "KFJSDKLŞGJSkldfsggdgsaagrdrgfdjfklsajk1234567890!@#$%^&*()1234567890!@#$%^&*()";
    public string Generate(int id)
    {
        var symmetricSecurityKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(secureKey));
        var credentials = new SigningCredentials(symmetricSecurityKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature);
        var header = new JwtHeader(credentials);
        header.Add("kid", "unique_key_id");
        var payload = new JwtPayload(id.ToString(), null, null, null, DateTime.Today.AddDays(1));
        var token = new JwtSecurityToken(header, payload);
        return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);
    }
    public JwtSecurityToken Verify(string jwt)
    {
        var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(secureKey);
        tokenHandler.ValidateToken(jwt, new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            ValidateIssuer = false,
            ValidateAudience = false
        }, out SecurityToken validatedToken);
        return (JwtSecurityToken)validatedToken;
    }
}
```

```
public IActionResult User()
{
    try
    {
        var jwt = Request.Cookies["jwt"];
        var token = _jwtService.Verify(jwt);
        int userId = int.Parse(token.Issuer);
        var user = _repository.GetById(userId);
        return Ok(user);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return Unauthorized();
    }
}
```

When i tried get request to User() there is an exception called Signature validation failed. Token does not have a kid.When i asked this to gpt he suggest the adding kid in the Generate method like below
header.Add("kid", "unique_key_id");
but it didn't work please help me

Comment: If you're already using cookies then you don't need to be using a JWT. JWTs and other bearer-tokens are meant for headless clients, not browser-based clients.

Comment: `int.Parse(token.Issuer);` <-- [The `iss` claim is meant to be a URI, not an integer](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7519#section-4.1.1).

Comment: The `kid` claim is the **Key Identifier** claim - it's only needed when you're dealing with PKI infrastructure and have nontrivial IdP+RP set-ups - it isn't necessary in simple cases like yours (i.e. where your IdP and RP are the same). Anyway, you can't use `ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true` if your signing credentials cannot actually be independently verified, so ignore that property.

Comment: Hi @Enes Tanis, you said you get the exception when call the request to User, but you can see that you never call the Generate method in your request, you just call the Verify method, so why you add the kid to the Generate method.